# Embedded jetty with singe page application

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded Jetty server serving up static files (html, images, css, javascript) ...

The index.html is a single page application.

How can I configure the embedded Jetty to serve index.html in case a certain path is invoked ... for instance:

- http://some.server.com/ -> returns **index.html**
- http://some.server.com/path -> returns **index.html**
- http://some.server.com/other/path -> returns **index.html**
- http://some.server.com/images/image.jpg -> returns **image.jpg**

Comment: Create annotated with @Controller class and create a methods with 
`@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/path", "/other/path"})
public ModelAndView getIndex(){
return new ModelAndView("index");
}`

Comment: How I can understood it's Spring-boot application?

Comment: It not a Spring application ... it is a standalone app (JAR) with Jetty embedded ... plus I don't want to list all paths ...

Comment: Try this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html

Comment: Or this: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Comment: (1) Which version of Jetty?  (2) How have you configured Jetty to serve up the static files so far?  This is pretty easy to do, but I can get you a better answer with those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is the solution I came up with ... not sure if it is the most elegant but it works.

```
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
servletContextHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
servletContextHandler.setResourceBase(webDir);
servletContextHandler.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");


ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
errorHandler.addErrorPage(404, "/"); // return root ... being index.html
servletContextHandler.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

I would prefer to handle this with some sort of pattern instead of reacting to 404's ...